# Android BUCK build error

Tags: android, buck

I am getting the following error when trying to build the buck sample project following these instructions (https://buckbuild.com/setup/getting_started.html).

```
BUILD FAILED: No native platforms detected. Probably Android NDK is not configured properly.
```

Repository setup in ~/.profile

```
export ANDROID_NDK_REPOSITORY=/Users/tm/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

Version according to source.properties file in ndk-bundle directory.

```
Pkg.Revision = 15.2.4203891
```

NDK setup in .buckconfig file

```
[ndk]
ndk_version = 15.2.4203891
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that when you run `buck` command the environment contains `ANDROID_NDK_REPOSITORY` variable:

```
echo $ANDROID_NDK_REPOSITORY
```

Also, `/Users/tm/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle` directory should contain a subdirectory `android-ndk-r15` that contains NDK v15 so that, for example,  `source.properties` has this location: `/Users/tm/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/android-ndk-r15/source.properties`.